# is the function $f$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Tags: real-analysis, limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

Let$f(x,y)$ be defined as

$x^2y^2\over\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ if $(x,y) \ne (0,0)$,

$0$ if $(x,y) = (0,0)$.

is $f$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

I am trying to prove that it is differentiable by computing the partial derivative and show that the partial derivative is continous at $(0,0)$ and hence the whole domain, but so far I cannot even find a way to show the limit of derivative exist at $(0,0)$.

Could someone show steps of finding that limit? Thanks!

May I ask for a proof without the usage of polar coordinate?

Comment: can you write down the partial derivatives you found ?

Comment: @Bleuderk $y^{2}(x^{3}+2xy^{2})/(x^{2}+y^{2})^{3/2}$

Comment: Without polar coordinates I think there is no simple way to show it. This exercize is made to use polar coordinates.

Comment: @Crostul I am not asking to find limit of the original function but its derivative. So is it still impossible?

Answer (score 1):

To show that $f$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$ you have to show that
$$f(h)=f(0,0)+\nabla f (0,0) \cdot h + o(|h|)$$
for $h \in \Bbb{R}^2$ in a neighbourhood of $(0,0)$ (here $\cdot$ denotes the scalar product). It is natural to put $\nabla f (0,0) = (0,0)$, so that indeed you need to prove
$$\lim_{h \to (0,0)} \frac{f(h)-f(0,0)}{|h|} =0$$
Using polar coordinates $h=(R \cos \theta , R \sin \theta)$ you have
$$0 \le \frac{f(h)-f(0,0)}{|h|} = \frac{R^4 \cos^2 \theta \sin^2 \theta}{R^2} \le R^2 \to 0$$
and you are done.

Comment: This method has not be taught in my university. Is it possible to do it by proving the derivative I calculated is 0 at (0,0)?

Comment: @Y.X.: No, you need to compute the partial derivatives at the origin using the *definition*. The expression you have is only valid for $(x,y)\neq(0,0)$, and since you don't know in advance whether the partial derivatives are continuous or not, you don't know if the limit of that expression as you approach the origin says anything about the true value there.

Comment: @Y.X.: Also with your original strategy (showing that the partials are continuous), you need to compute their value at the origin separately.

Comment: @HansLundmark I know that the derivative at (0,0) is 0, but how to conclude that it is continous at zero?

Comment: @Y.X. How is it possible that this method has not be taught to you? This is the standard definition of differentiability in more variables (see [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_the_derivative#Multivariable_calculus) ). What is your definition of differentiability, then?

Comment: @Y.X.: To show that $f_x$ is continuous at the origin, you need to check that $f_x(x,y) \to f(0,0)$ as $(x,y)\to(0,0)$. The easiest way is to rewrite the expression for $f_x(x,y)$ in polar coordinates, and let $r\to0$.

Answer (score -1):

Hmm from what I recall from calculus 2 courses you can show this function in polar coordinates 
$X = r\cos(\theta)$
$Y=r\sin(\theta)$
Now we can see that $\sqrt(x^2+y+2)$ in polar coordinates will be equal to $r$
Then $f=r^4*\sin^2(\theta)*\cos^2(\theta) / r$
Then you can see the $\lim$ will be $0$ because $r\to 0$
You can use the polar coordinates for the derivatives.

Comment: This is not an answer, and it is unreadable.